# Failure to mount partition

Tags: partitioning, mount

I receive the following error when trying to mount /dev/sda1 ,an ext4 partition:

```
Error mounting /dev/sda1 at /run/media/andrew/3a3aa528-cad4-4487-9ed3-b8667ca103e2: mount(2) system call failed: No such file or directory.
```

Hang on...

It wasn't there, I mkdir'ed it and I still get the same error. Gparted shows sda1 as fine and 10% full. Any ideas?? Thanks.

---

```
[andrew@broom Desktop]$ sudo mount /dev/sda1 --target /run/media/andrew/3a3aa528-cad4-4487-9ed3-b8667ca103e2
mount: /run/media/andrew/3a3aa528-cad4-4487-9ed3-b8667ca103e2: mount(2) system call failed: No such file or directory.
[andrew@broom Desktop]$ cd /run/media/andrew
[andrew@broom andrew]$ ls
3a3aa528-cad4-4487-9ed3-b8667ca103e2
[andrew@broom andrew]$
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Can you explain why you are trying to mount it to a special filesystem (`tmpfs`) below /run? Have you tried other locations like subfolders of `/mnt`, `/media` or your home folder?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/stuff
sudo mount -t auto /dev/sda1 /mnt/stuff
```

Then do what you want to with the "stuff" and when finished use:

```
sudo umount -l /mnt/stuff
sudo rm -d /mnt/stuff
```

This is from an interactive script I wrote last week: [Unable to read files between two distros](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034739/unable-to-read-files-between-two-distros/1034746#1034746)