# why fdisk doesn't show hard disk(/dev/sdf) while lsblk shows hard disk(/dev/sdf)?

Tags: hard-drive, fdisk

I'm trying to mount additional hard disk.

`lsblk` shows /dev/sdf1..3. However, `sudo fdisk -l` doesn't show /dev/sdf1..3

What is the problem?

Comment: Please run `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdf` and post the result.

Comment: It says "fdisk: cannot open /dev/sdf: Input/output error"

Comment: I wrote a bash script to let you choose `lsblk` entries to mount. Another script lets you un mount. See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034739/unable-to-read-files-between-two-distros/1034746#1034746

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that `sudo fdisk -l`-l, --list

**From man page:**

> List the partition tables for the specified devices and then exit.   If
>                 no devices are given, those mentioned in /proc/partitions (if that file
>                 exists) are used.

That means, only that devices are listed which are in the output of

```
less /proc/partitions
```

Comment: Thank you, /proc/partitions has /dev/sdf series. But, the result is not shown in sudo fdisk -l. This makes me to trouble with mounting.