# How do you uninstall Ubuntu?

Tags: uninstall, drive

I have a PC with three hard drives and a quad-boot set up with Windows 10, Ubuntu 18.04, Ubuntu 16.10 and Kali Linux - Rolling. Because I don't use the last two of these anymore, I'd like to remove them to free the space. I can't use a live CD because the PC I'm working on doesn't have a disk reader.  Additionally I'm not even sure on which partition Ubuntu 16.10 and Kali Linux are installed.  They could be on the same physical disk as far as I know. So, how do I establish on which drive these two partitions are located in order to uninstall them?  Note that I wish to keep Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Don't Uninstall, reformat the partition

Firstly you don't "uninstall" Ubuntu 16.10 or Kali-Linux, you simply reformat the partition they are sitting in. Most people would probably use NTFS (Windows format) but you can use `ext4` for Linux if you like.

NTFS has the advantage as it can be written to and read by both Windows and Linux. `ext4` can only be read and written by Linux unless extraordinary steps are taken in Windows with the possibility of data corruption.

You can reformat the partitions in `gparted` or a number of other programs.

## Finding what the partitions are

There are a few ways of discovering the correct partitions to reformat.

### Using `lsblk` to reveal partition device name

If when you installed Ubuntu 16.10 and Kali Linux you gave the partitions a label they would be revealed with the `lsblk` command:

```
$ lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,LABEL,MOUNTPOINT,SIZE,MODEL
NAME         FSTYPE LABEL            MOUNTPOINT   SIZE MODEL
sr0                                              1024M DVD+/-RW DW316  
sda                                             931.5G HGST HTS721010A9
├─sda4       ntfs   WINRETOOLS                    450M 
├─sda2                                            128M 
├─sda5       ntfs   Image                        11.4G 
├─sda3       ntfs   HGST_Win10       /mnt/d       919G 
└─sda1       vfat   ESP                           500M 
nvme0n1                                           477G Samsung SSD 960 PRO 512GB            
├─nvme0n1p5  ntfs                                 858M 
├─nvme0n1p3                                        16M 
├─nvme0n1p1  ntfs                                 450M 
├─nvme0n1p8  ntfs   Shared_WSL+Linux /mnt/e         9G 
├─nvme0n1p6  ext4   New_Ubuntu_16.04 /           23.7G 
├─nvme0n1p4  ntfs   NVMe_Win10       /mnt/c     363.2G 
├─nvme0n1p10 ext4   Ubuntu_18.04     /mnt/clone  27.2G 
├─nvme0n1p2  vfat                    /boot/efi     99M 
├─nvme0n1p9  swap                    [SWAP]       7.9G 
└─nvme0n1p7  ext4   Old_Ubuntu_16.04 /mnt/old    44.6G
```

Imagine I wanted to reformat the partitions **Ubuntu 18.04** and **Old_Ubuntu_16.04** I would reference them as `/dev/nvme0n1p10` and `/dev/nvme0n1p7` within `gparted` or any other partition formatting program. Of course they would likely display the LABEL as well so using `lsblk` might be unnecessary.

### Mount the partition and read `/etc/lsb-release`

From your terminal (of your currently booted Ubuntu) type:

```
$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS"
```

We can repeat this command (with minor modification) on every partition after mounting it.

#### Mount partition

Some people probably find it very easy to mount partitions but I wrote a script for it. I run `sudo mount-menu.sh` and get this selection screen:

[image]

Your Ubuntu 16.10 and Kali partitions will probably be `FSTYPE` of `ext4`. They will definitely not be `ntfs` or `vfat`. For this example I'll pick `nvme0n1p10` to see what distribution is installed there (yes we can already guess it is Ubuntu 18.04).

Use the Down Arrow key to highlight it and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. The menu will clear and you are left with a message in your terminal:

```
=====================================================================
Mount Device:  /dev/nvme0n1p10
Mount Name:    /mnt/mount-menu.jcXDv
File System:   ext4
ID:            Ubuntu
RELEASE:       16.04
CODENAME:      xenial
DESCRIPTION:   Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
 Size  Used Avail Use%
  27G  9.4G   16G  38%
```

#### Mounted partition's `/etc/lsb-release`

Now we can repeat the command from the last section with a minor modification:

```
$ cat /mnt/mount-menu.jcXDv/etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS"
```

Yes I know it looks wrong but I cloned my Ubuntu 16.04 over to the 18.04 partition recently to test Ubuntu's 16.04 to 18.04 upgrade process (it's a hobby of mine).

#### Unmount the partition

The next step is to unmount the partition. I also wrote a script to do that `sudo umount-menu.sh`:

[image: umount-menu.sh]

Highlight the partition you mounted in the last step and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

The menu will clear and a message will be display:

```
=====================================================================

/dev/nvme0n1p10 mounted on /mnt/mount-menu.jcXDv unmounted.
```

---

You can find both scripts here: [Unable to read files between two distros](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034739/unable-to-read-files-between-two-distros/1034746#1034746)